# How many bonds can nitrogen form?

Tags: bond, coordination-compounds, electronic-configuration

As known, nitrogen could form 3 bonds based on octet rule, because it has 5 valence electrons. That means it needs 3 bonds.

On the other hand, why sometimes nitrogen forms 4 bonds?

[image]

Comment: Because lone pairs can make dipolar bonds...

Comment: The title and the question are somewhat incoherent. The question is rather trivial, whereas the title is quite interesting. If this is about the **maximum** number of  bonds, I would answer I saw a structure with 7.

Comment: @andselisk True, but the original title (prior to the edit) was even *more* interesting ;)

Comment: @paracetamol Ah, the mighty sodium. Probably OP should clarify what exactly is expected from the answer.

Comment: I want to know in which conditions could nitrogen or other elements form more than it is supposed to?

Comment: Well, for nitrogen the richest coordination environment I know is a capped trigonal prism, C.N. 7 (Costa, M.; Della Pergola, R.; Fumagalli, A.; Laschi, F.; Losi, S.; Macchi, P.; Sironi, A.; Zanello, P. Inorg. Chem. 2007, 46 (2), 552–560. DOI 10.1021/ic0608288). But this is a rather non-standard case as the $\ce{N}$ atom is trapped inside a metal framework.

Comment: Insert Professor Klapötke who is certain that $\ce{NF5}$ exists but hasn’t been synthesised yet.

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to try answer the question from the title regarding the maximum number of atoms nitrogen is capable of bonding with, and also slightly expand my comment.

[Metal nitrido complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_nitrido_complex) are commonly known to have up to 6 metal centers bound with a single bridging $\ce{N3−}$ ion, located in an octahedral cavity. An interstitial nitrogen can contribute 5 electrons, and the rest is provided by the group 9 and 10 metals which are electron-rich (typically, $\ce{Rh}$, $\ce{Ir}$).

There are few more exceptions where formal C.N. for nitrogen is 7: complexes of lithium amides based on $\ce{\{Li14N10\}^{6-}}$ cluster framework [1,2] and an inclusion nitrido-cluster $\ce{\{Co2RhN2\}^{3-}}$ [3]. Unfortunately in both crystal structures [1,2] with 6- and 7-fold coordinated nitrogens of $\ce{N-Ar}$ groups those are heavily disordered. Structure [3] is more suitable for the representation.

**tris(Tetramethylammonium)($\mu_7$-nitrido)-($\mu_6$-nitrido)-decakis($\mu_2$-carbonyl)-undecacarbonyl-deca-cobalt-rhodium(I)** $\ce{[Co10RhN2(CO)21]^3-}$ [3] contains two non-equivalent 6- and 7-fold coordinated nitrogen atoms ($\mathrm{N2}$ and $\mathrm{N1}$, respectively), sharing a triangular face:

$\color{#909090}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{C}$;
$\color{#3050F8}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{N}$;
$\color{#FF0D0D}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{O}$;
$\color{#F090A0}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Co}$;
$\color{#0A7D8C}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Rh}$;

[image]

Cluster core wireframe model without carbonyl ligands:

[image]

Atom $\mathrm{N1}$ with C.N. 7 is coordinated with 6 cobalts and 1 rhodium, forming a capped trigonal prism. Interestingly enough, $\mathrm{Co1}$ is a capping atom, not rhodium:

[image]

```
     N1   SYMM Co5   Co4   Co6   Co3   Co2  Rh1  Co1
Co5  1.90 I    -     -     -     -     -    -    -  
Co4  1.91 I    135.0 -     -     -     -    -    -  
Co6  1.92 I    79.5  80.2  -     -     -    -    -  
Co3  1.98 I    129.7 85.1  80.2  -     -    -    -  
Co2  2.00 I    82.3  140.2 128.4 75.4  -    -    -  
Rh1  2.18 I    80.7  81.1  128.3 144.9 95.3 -    -  
Co1  2.43 I    143.5 70.3  136.5 66.4  70.1 78.6 -
```

Both interstitial nitrogens play the role of *internal ligands*, which provide 
cluster valence electrons (CVE), but don't contribute to steric hindrance between external ligands such as carbonyls, making the cluster more stable [4, ch. 1.18]

#### Bibliography

1. Armstrong, D. R.; Barr, D.; Clegg, W.; Drake, S. R.; Singer, R. J.; Snaith, R.; Stalke, D.; Wright, D. S. *Angew. Chem. Int. Ed. Engl.* **1991**, 30 (12), 1707–1709. DOI [10.1002/anie.199117071](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.199117071).
2. Armstrong, D. R.; Ball, S. C.; Barr, D.; Clegg, W.; Linton, D. J.; Kerr, L. C.; Moncrieff, D.; Raithby, P. R.; Singer, R. J.; Snaith, R.; Stalke, D.; Wheatley, A. E. H.; Wright, D. S. *J. Chem. Soc., Dalton Trans.* **2002**, 0 (12), 2505–2511. DOI [10.1039/B107970K](https://doi.org/10.1039/b107970k).
3. Costa, M.; Della Pergola, R.; Fumagalli, A.; Laschi, F.; Losi, S.; Macchi, P.; Sironi, A.; Zanello, P. *Inorg. Chem.* **2007**, 46 (2), 552–560. DOI [10.1021/ic0608288](https://doi.org/10.1021/ic0608288).
4. *Metal clusters in chemistry*; Oro, L. A., Braunstein, P., Raithby, P. R., Eds.; Wiley-VCH: Weinheim; New York, 1999. ISBN 978-3-527-29549-4.

Comment: while esoteric examples with high numbers of "bonds" are fascinating, the OP was asking about the far more basic case of why nitrogen can form 4 covalent bonds. For that question, this answer probably just confuses (though it would be a good one to a different question).

Comment: How can nitrogen form [this compound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VGf0.png) then? It cannot donate 2 electrons (coordinate covalent bond) to the R-group as the R-group only *needs* 1 electron for an octet.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic I'm not sure how this is related to the answer or why post a simple formula as an image, but it's just an [isocyanide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isocyanide) which exists as resonant hybrid of two canonical forms: bipolar with a negative charge on the carbon atom and carbene with divalent carbon.

Answer (score 7):

Nitrogen has three electrons in its 2p orbital. Therefore, it can form three bonds by sharing its three electrons.
It cannot accept any more electrons but here's how it forms the fourth bond.

Nitrogen has one lone pair of electrons in its 2s orbital. It can donate this electron pair to form a coordinate bond. This coordinate bond that nitrogen forms by donating its electron pair to the vacant orbital of other atom is how it can form 4 bonds.

Comment: How can nitrogen form [this compound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VGf0.png) then? It cannot donate 2 electrons (coordinate covalent bond) to the R-group as it only *needs* 1 electron for an octet.